# Top N rows per group only getting 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to show the top 3 (or any number) housings per category. The top meaning the most visited. So if I have a table like this:

```
+------------+--------------------+--------+
| housing_id | category           | visits |
+------------+--------------------+--------+
|          7 | cat                |      2 |
|          8 | New Category       |      1 |
|         10 | bead and breakfast |      1 |
|         11 | bead and breakfast |      4 |
|         15 | 2                  |      3 |
|         16 | 2                  |      1 |
|         17 | New Category       |      1 |
|         18 | cat                |      1 |
+------------+--------------------+--------+
```

I and I want to select the top 3 most visited housings per category so I am doing this.

```
select housing_id, category, visits
from
    (select housing_id, category, visits,
        @category_rank := if(@current_category = category, @country_rank + 1, 1) as category_rank,
        @current_category := category
    from visit_counts
    order by category, visits desc
    ) ranked
where category_rank <= 3;
```

I get:

```
+------------+--------------------+--------+
| housing_id | category           | visits |
+------------+--------------------+--------+
|         15 | 2                  |      3 |
|         11 | bead and breakfast |      4 |
|          7 | cat                |      2 |
|          8 | New Category       |      1 |
+------------+--------------------+--------+
```

but I want:

```
+------------+--------------------+--------+
| housing_id | category           | visits |
+------------+--------------------+--------+
|         15 | 2                  |      3 |
|         16 | 2                  |      1 |
|         11 | bead and breakfast |      4 |
|         10 | bead and breakfast |      1 |
|          7 | cat                |      2 |
|         18 | cat                |      1 |
|          8 | New Category       |      1 |
|         17 | New Category       |      1 |
+------------+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: not really anything to with java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the user variables without declaring them. Also, you should assign and read the user variables in one expression as the MySQL doesnt guarantee the order of column evaluation (so assignment may happen before or after you read it).

Try this:

```
select housing_id, category, visits
from (
    select housing_id, category, visits,
        @category_rank := if(@current_category = category, 
                                @category_rank + 1,
                                if(@current_category := category, 1, 1)
                            ) as category_rank
    from visit_counts, (select @category_rank := 0, @current_category := null) t2
    order by category, visits desc
    ) ranked
where category_rank <= 3;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/JJQ87458)